# How to print the last line of passwd in sections in bash shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I am very new to bash shell scripting and I have an assignment that wants me to read the last line of a copy of my linux installations (that is in the admin folder) passwd file which contains the user name, real name, home directory and login shell. I have tried the read command but it continues to output the entire file rather than just the last line and even so I need to be able to output in in sections, for example: `echo $Username` would output Admin or echo `$Realname` wold ouptut the users real name. I have also tried sed but I get a "cant read, no such file or directory error"

Edit: After receiving an email from my professor, I DO have to use the read command to get the information from the passwd file. However your responses have proved useful in helping me understand what I am doing so far. Thank you!

[Here is a link to my list of objectives in this script](http://gyazo.com/8fc774945645bc0195a2257d89411c3d.png)

and here is the code that I have written that returns the entire passwd file:

```
file="/home/Admin/passwd"

while read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7
do
        echo "Username: $f1, Realname: $f2, Homedir: $f3, loginshell: $f4 "
done < "$file"
```

any help would be greatly appreciated, somehow I feel like I'm reading too much into the instructions but I would like some other opinions, thank you!

Comment: As this is an assignment I'm not going to give you a complete answer, but look at the man page for the tail command.

Comment: Also look into the use of IFS to chose a field separator for the read command so fields are split properly. Find out what field separator the password file uses.

Comment: +1 to Scrutinizer's comment: what is the field separator?

Comment: thank you, I managed to get tail working to print the last line, however I am wondering if you have any tips on how to use IFS in conjunction with Tail? Or do I have to use Read? Thank you! The field separator in the passwd file is ":" (colon)

Comment: You can use a tool like [`sel`](https://github.com/slezica/sel)

Comment: can you use awk - gawk -F: 'END {print $1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $4 " " $5 " " $6 " " $7 }' /etc/passwd

Comment: @Talldarkandmoe I tried to answer you but there where a small problem...so I asked [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22139700/capture-a-file-and-separate-columns-and-add-sth-using-arrays) and got best answers

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the wonderful world of scripting!

Assignment does not seem to mention to use 'read' command, so, not giving out the solution completely, I would suggest you use redirection methods (try a Google search on Unix redirection, it is quite fun!)

I would also suggest searching on standard and error redirection in Unix. There are some nifty shortcuts quite easy to find.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you need use IFS to define the field separator, then understand what column is home directory, and login shell.

Understanding fields in /etc/passwd (http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcpasswd-file-format/)

Here is the fix:

```
file="/home/Admin/passwd"

while IFS=: read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7
do
   echo "Username: $f1, Realname: $f5, Homedir: $f6, loginshell: $f7 "
done  < "$file"
```