# capture a file and separate columns and add sth using arrays

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, awk

I want to manage my **/etc/passwd** and add names for each column..

I want to read from array...

What I tried is the following bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE="/etc/passwd"
arr=( $(awk < $FILE -F: '{print $1 $5 $6 $7}') )

for Username Realname Homedir Loginshell in "${arr[@]}"; do
    result=$(printf 'Username: %s Realname: %s Homedir: %s Loginshell: %s' "$Username" "$Realname" "$Homedir" "Loginshell")
    echo "$result"
done
```

But there is the error:

```
./u.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `Realname'
./u.sh: line 6: `for Username Realname Homedir Loginshell in "${arr[@]}"; do'
```

**The second question is:**

How can I read `$FILE` as an argument in such scripts...because when change the script like:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$#" -ne "1" ]; then
    echo "Usage: `basename $0` <input-file>"
    exit 1
fi

arr=( $(awk < $1 -F: '{print $1 $2 $6 $7}') )

for Username Realname Homedir Loginshell in "${arr[@]}"; do
    result=$(printf 'Username: %s Realname: %s Homedir: %s Loginshell: %s' "$Username" "$Realname" "$Homedir" "Loginshell")
    echo "$result"
done
```

It would crash...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach avoids `awk` but using bash's `IFS` to separate the fields in `FILE`:

```
FILE="/etc/passwd"
while IFS=: read Username pass uid gid Realname Homedir Loginshell; do
    result=$(printf 'Username: %s Realname: %s Homedir: %s Loginshell: %s' "$Username" "$Realname" "$Homedir" "$Loginshell")
    echo "$result"
done <"$FILE"
```

To supply the file name as an argument (as per question 2):

```
if [ "$#" -ne "1" ]; then
    echo "Usage: `basename $0` <input-file>"
    exit 1
fi
FILE=$1

while IFS=: read Username pass uid gid Realname Homedir Loginshell; do
    result=$(printf 'Username: %s Realname: %s Homedir: %s Loginshell: %s' "$Username" "$Realname" "$Homedir" "$Loginshell")
    echo "$result"
done <"$FILE"
```

If you want to use arrays, then:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$#" -ne "1" ]; then
    echo "Usage: `basename $0` <input-file>"
    exit 1
fi
FILE=$1

#declare -a fields
IFS=:
while read line; do
    fields=($line)
    result=$(printf 'Username: %s Realname: %s Homedir: %s Loginshell: %s' "${fields[0]}" "${fields[4]}" "${fields[5]}" "${fields[6]}")
    echo "$result"
done <"$FILE"
```

The above reads `/etc/passwd` one line at a time.  With `IFS` set to a colon, each line is then converted to an array using `fields=($line)`.  To avoid surprises, you may want to reset `IFS` to its default value before  executing any `bash` code that depends on `bash`'s normal word separation rules.

#### Extra:

Here is an attempt at pretty-printing the output:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$#" -ne "1" ]; then
    echo "Usage: `basename $0` <input-file>"
    exit 1
fi
FILE=$1

{
echo "========:========:=======:=========="
echo "Username:Realname:Homedir:Loginshell"
echo "========:========:=======:=========="

IFS=:
while read line; do
    fields=($line)
    echo "${fields[0]}:${fields[4]}:${fields[5]}:${fields[6]}"
done < "$FILE"
} | column -nts:
```

By default, `column` separates fields by whitespace.  However, the realname output field can contain spaces. So, the `-s:` option is used so that `column` uses colon-separated fields on input.  To assure that headings lined up with the data fields, both headings and data are submitted to the same instance of `column`.

Comment: could you possibly thell what does `[ "${fields[0]}" ] || break` and `< <(sed 's/:/\n/g' "$FILE")` do?

Comment: pardon, The second thing: It doesn't show me all lines in passwd... why?

Comment: @MortezaLSC Explanation added for those two items.  Let me know if you need more detail.  I just re-tested all three approaches on my passwd file and it read all the way to the end.  I cannot reproduce the error that you are seeing.

Comment: the first two answers are correct..and very good..the answer used by arrays is my problem..when I run this script...`wc -l /etc/passwd = 36` and `./scipt.sh /etc/passwd | wc -l=18` shouldn't we change `readarray -tn7` ?

Comment: Thank you...now `./scipt.sh /etc/passwd | wc -l= 32` not 36 yet

Comment: @MortezaLSC I just edited in a different approach.  Please test it on your /etc/passwd file and let me know.

Comment: excellent... very good ... thanks :)...I really learned something

Answer (score 2):

Use it like this:

```
while read Username Realname Homedir Loginshell; do
    result=$(printf "Username: %s Realname: %s Homedir: %s Loginshell: %s" "$Username" "$Realname" "$Homedir" "Loginshell")
    echo "$result"
done < <(awk -F: '{print $1 $2 $6 $7}' /etc/passwd)
```

**EDIT:** You can just use awk:

```
if (($# == 0)); then
   echo "Usage: `basename $0` <input-file>"
   exit 1
fi
FILENAME="$1"

awk -F: '{printf "Username: %s Realname: %s Homedir: %s Loginshell: %s\n",
       $1, $2, $6, $7}' "$FILENAME"
```

Comment: now the result is not good: `Username: rootx/root/bin/bash Realname:  Homedir:  Loginshell: Loginshell`

Comment: You can just pass filename as argument and use `$1` inside the script.

Comment: I know but when we use awk with $1 it confuses I think...and your answer doesn't work as well/// see the result please

Comment: and better to use arrays... Thank you....Your answer was now correct because the result is: `Username: rootx/root/bin/bash Realname:  Homedir:  Loginshell: Loginshell`

Comment: Yes very good :) .... Could you possibly say how is it possible with arrays? It would be an exercise...and also how to read as argument?

Comment: I could assist you but for this problem BASH arrays aren't a recommended solution.

Comment: In general one should not attempt to use  a particular method for solving a problem if it involves writing long complicated code which is usually solvable by an alternate simple command. Your problem is best solved by awk 1 liner as I showed above. Rest I can produce 5 alternatives in shell to solve it by making it complicated but real solution still remains same which is awk.

Comment: I agree with you..But what I tried to do was about arrays as an exercise in order to do solve more complicated scripts really...Thank you..you helped me again as always...